# Js is able to execute only after page loads all elements

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with my javascript. It only only load and can execute the scripts after the page loads all the others elements..

For example, on my menu-mobile, i can only hit the hamburguer-menu only after the page loads all others elements.. causing a "delay" for the user.

My structure of the head is that:

```
<head>
        <meta charset="UFT-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <title><?= $config['head']['title']; ?></title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?= $config['head']['icon-Path']; ?>" type="image/png">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width: <?= $config['layout']['small']['0']; ?>px) and (max-width: <?= $config['layout']['small']['1']; ?>px)" href="/styles/small.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width: <?= $config['layout']['medium']['0']; ?>px) and (max-width: <?= $config['layout']['medium']['1']; ?>px)" href="/styles/medium.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width: <?= $config['layout']['medium-large']['0']; ?>px) and (max-width: <?= $config['layout']['medium-large']['1']; ?>px)" href="/styles/medium-large.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width: <?= $config['layout']['large']['0']; ?>px)" href="/styles/large.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/owl.carousel.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/scripts.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/main.js"></script>
    </head>
```

Anyone could help me? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try add async to scripts that you want to load immediately

Let me know if that helped

Comment: I have setup like this: <script async src="/js/main.js"></script> but didn't works.

Comment: Try putting main.js above other script tags or even links maybe that will help

Comment: Do you have this project on github? If you would share it I could see how it's working